# How Would I achive this line effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, drop-shadow

I'm trying to recreate the circled line effect in the image below.  I have tried bevel and emboss and also had a go with an ellipse and drop shadow but just can't recreating it convincingly. [image]

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, why are you using effects instead of simply drawing a circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I got your question right, it's a pretty simple principle:

1. Create a layer with a gray background
2. Create a blank layer over it
3. Use the Elliptical Marquee Tool to create an ellipse and fill it with black (step 1 in image)
4. Add a Gaussian Blur that looks just right (step 2 in image)
5. Take the Rectangular Marquee Tool and delete half of the ellipse (step 3 in image)
6. Set the Blending Mode to Soft Light and use Transform (Ctrl+T) to rotate (step 4 in image)
7. Play with Opacity till you get the desired effect

[image]

Comment: @user3260707 You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I created this example as per the settings below.
Essentially a large faint drop shadow with a smaller but darker drop shadow over the top.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it

- Create a layer with a rectangle
- Add a drop shadow using the layer styles palette

[image]

- Add a layer mask

[image]

- Draw a circular a gradient in the mask (make sure it is 100% white to 100% RGB black)

[image]

- Group the layer. This is to prevent the next step from knocking out the background.

[image]

- Knockout the layer using blending mode in the layer styles palette. Make sure "Layer mask hides effects" is turned on.

[image]

Result

[image]